# python - combining and interpolating 2 dataframe column and creating unique number list from it

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have this 2 integer column in my dataframe

```
from | to 
----------
 1   |  4
 2   |  4
 3   |  6
```

I want to combine them as such I am getting a list like this:
`[1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 6]`

Then I want to create a unique value from that list like this:
`[1, 4, 2, 3, 6]`

How do I do that?

For combining and interpolating the 2 dataframes, I tried this:

`' '.join(df['from'].astype('str') + ' ' + df['to'].astype('str'))`

But I have to convert them to string first, join all the string, then split it again. I am looking for more straightforward way to do it.

For finding unique values in a list, I tried:

`list(set(non_unique_list))`

But the resulting list is: `[1,2,3,4,6]` which is something that I am not looking for. I am looking for in particularly this order: `[1, 4, 2, 3, 6]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) are what you're looking for:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'from': [1,2,3], 'to':[4,4,6]})
>>> df
   from  to
0     1   4
1     2   4
2     3   6
>>> df.stack()
0  from    1
   to      4
1  from    2
   to      4
2  from    3
   to      6
dtype: int64
>>> df.stack().unique()
array([1, 4, 2, 3, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

@addicted

You're extremely close to what you want to achieve. Once you achieve the `non_unique_list` of items by joining the dataframe columns, you can take this list and get the resulting order by doing the following

```
final_order_list = [non_unique_list[i] for i in range(len(non_unique_list)) if i == non_unique_list.index(non_unique_list[i])]
```

The final result looks as follows:

```
>>> final_order_list 
['1', '4', '2', '3', '6']
```